# Marked trail off the Beartooth Highway to a peak

Tags: hiking, trails, mountains

I'm looking for a marked trail off the [Beartooth highway](http://beartoothhighway.com/) that leads to a peak with a nice overview about the region. I googled for the last couple of hours, but couldn't find a lot of information. Is there such a trail?

The highway winds its way through southwest Montana and northwest Wyoming and leads into Yellowstone National Park at its Northeast Entrance.

Comment: Have you completed your journey to the Beartooth Highway?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a trail.  At the top of the bear tooth hwy you are above the tree line.  You can stop along the hwy and see for miles.

When you get to [Top of the World](http://www.topoftheworldresort.com/) there are some trees, but not far from there you can see forever.

I took this way into the park, the views are extraordinary.

Comment: Well, that's ridiculous. Just because I can see for miles, does not necessarily mean that I do not need a trail.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException the highway is the path "that leads to a peak with a nice overview about the region" there is no vegetation more then a couple inches high, you can see farther then you can walk in a day. You will feel like you have driven to the top of the world.

Comment: but you don't need a trail *off*  the beartooth hwy to find a nice overview, beause you get that overview from hwy itself.

Comment: @njzk2 yep, they will understand when they get there.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of trails that are accessed from the Beartooth Highway.  What you need is a map of the Eastern Absaroka-Beartooth Wilderness.

[image: Absaroka-Beartooth east]
[amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1566955823)

I've poked around a few of them.  It's lovely country.  I especially enjoy all of the fantastic little lakes.  Although, the best views of the area do come from the top of the pass, as @James_Jenkins noted.

Answer (score 1):

I've been up on Beartooth a handful of times. I almost always find somewhere new to explore and kill a few hours. Look for pullouts and see if there is any kind of trail head. The lakes and streams up there are beautiful. Bring bear spray, it's grizzly country.

Comment: And don't worry about surprise encounters with the wildlife -- bears aren't very good at hiding behind blades of grass.